# more how many different possibilities stuff in a row

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

There's 4 green m&m, 5 red m&m, 8 blue m&m, 10 yellow m&m. In how many ways can you line them all up in a row. I believe the answer is 25840847132100 from an online total combinations generator but I do not know how to arrive at that answer. Please explain how you can get that, if that's correct.

And how do you find the probably that all of the m&ms with the same colors are all next to one another? (e.g. GGGGRRRRRBBBBBBBBYYYYYYYYYY)

Comment: Total arrangements $\frac{27!}{4!5!8!10!} \approx 2.584\times 10^{13}$. $4!=24$ arrangements of solid color blocks. About $10^{-12}$ chance of that by random arrangement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the multinomial

$$
\binom{27}{4, 5, 8, 10} = \frac{27!}{4!5!8!10!} = 25840847132100
$$

In answer to your second question: There are only $4! = 24$ distinct ways to line the candies in a row in the way you describe.  However, because all the candies of the same color are indistinguishable and can be interchanged, in order to determine the probability that a random arrangement will yield such an ordering, we must multiply by $4!5!8!10!$, divided by the total number of orderings, $27!$; that is,

$$
\frac{4!4!5!8!10!}{27!} \doteq 9.2876 \times 10^{-13}
$$